# JPQL/HQL queries using an associative table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have users and tasks. Each user can have multiple sets of tasks and vice-versa. I call users that are contained in tasks "Members", but i dont have a Member entity, it is implicit and declared thru annotation `@JoinTable(name = "member"...`. Code:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "member", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"))
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tasks")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    private Calendar initialDate;
    private Calendar finalDate;
}
```

My problem is in JPQL queries, since I dont have an Members real bean (@Entity annotated and stuff) I can't do anything on my repositories like (Assuming I have and Member entity wich maps an user and a task):

```
FROM User u
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
 FROM Member m WHERE m.task.finalDate >= :inicial AND m.task.finalDate <= :final
 AND m.user.id = u.id//Member here is a hipotetical/nonexistent entity 
)
```

Theres any way to to this query using JPQL/HQL or I'll need to fallback to native sql query?
Ty

Comment: clearly JPQL statements begin "SELECT {alias}" ...

Comment: never used select on HQL queries, it will solve any of my troubles?

Comment: it will mean that your queries are valid JPQL, i.e standards complaint JPA. Without it they are of no use anywhere but Hibernate ...

Comment: Ah, got it. But in this case I've created a hypothetical JPQL query, because I dont have a Member class (@Entity)... and Idk how to do this query i wrote without having this associative class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think for provided example you need to refer to Member entity (if exists). You probably can do something like:

```
from User u INNER JOIN u.tasks t WHERE t.finalData < :initial OR t.finalDate > :final
```

Comment: Member there is only a bogus entity, it really doesnt exist on my project, bu if it existed that would be the JPQ query. Ty, I will try your explanation.